# How to check focused Richtextbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two richtextbox in a form. I want to add a text by clicking a button. How do I know which richtextbox the cursor currently is?

My code is like this :

```
If rtbContent1.Focused = True Then
    rtbContent1.SelectedText = "New Text"
ElseIf rtbContent2.Focused = True Then
    rtbContent2.SelectedText = "New Text"
End If
```

But its not working.

Comment: Not tested: try to use the RichTextBox.Click event.

Comment: Can't you check both richtextboxs to see if they are empty and if it's not empty then add the text?

Comment: @Cal-cium I want to add the text where my cursor is placed. If i check they are not empty then it adds the new text always to the first richtextbox

Comment: @muffi RichTextBox click event also not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursot won't be in the textbox when you click the button, the focus will transfer to the button. But you can do this by keeping a reference to the last focused RichTextBox like so.

Attach Enter-event on both RichTextBoxes and store the last focused CheckBox in a private variable:

```
 Private lastFocusedTextBox As RichTextBox = Nothing

 Private Sub RichTextBoxes_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.Enter, RichTextBox2.Enter
     lastFocusedTextBox = CType(sender, RichTextBox)
 End Sub

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     If lastFocusedTextBox IsNot Nothing Then
        lastFocusedTextBox.SelectedText = "My Text"
     End If
 End Sub
```